# calculate hash in flutter flow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I am trying to calculate hash like below in flutter flow custom action

```
Future getHashAction() async {

String privateKey = "keyhere";

int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

var bytes = utf8.encode('$timestamp$privateKey');

var digest = await sha512.convert(bytes);

return digest.toString();

}
```

and it says Undefined name 'utf8', but I am not able to add import 'dart:convert' its gives error as its already building... is there any other way to calculate hash in flutter flow